# @tf_gradient peculiar implementation in StyleGan

Tags: tensorflow

I've been reading the source code for the StyleGAN implementation, and I cannot understand the peculiar use of the `@tf_gradient` decorator. Let us take the concrete example of their implementation of `Leaky_Relu`. The way I would do it is as follows :

```
def myLRelu(x,alpha=0.2):
    alpha = tf.constant(alpha, dtype=x.dtype, name='alpha')
    @tf.custom_gradient
    def func(x):
        y = tf.maximum(x, x * alpha)
        def grad(dy):
            dx = tf.where(y >= 0, dy, dy * alpha)
            return dx
        return y, grad
    return func(x)
```

Which follows the tf documentation for the use of tf.custom_gradient. But in the styleGan paper, they implement it as follows (I removed the "variable_scope" in my implementation as I'm not sure what it does):

```
def leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.2):
    with tf.variable_scope('LeakyReLU'):
        alpha = tf.constant(alpha, dtype=x.dtype, name='alpha')
        @tf.custom_gradient
        def func(x):
            y = tf.maximum(x, x * alpha)
            @tf.custom_gradient
            def grad(dy):
                dx = tf.where(y >= 0, dy, dy * alpha)
                return dx, lambda ddx: tf.where(y >= 0, ddx, ddx * alpha)
            return y, grad
        return func(x)
```

There are two `@tf.custom_gradient` decorators used, and I don't understand why since there clearly aren't any second order derivatives being computed (as they are identically 0 anyway for LRelu). Is this a trick to somehow speed up computations ? If so, how does it work ?

EDIT : To clarify why I think this is somehow a "trick" to make computations of gradients faster, the authors make the following comment in the code :

```
# High-level ops for manipulating 4D activation tensors.
# The gradients of these are meant to be as efficient as possible.
```

And for completeness, here is the [repo](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan/) from which I took the code from

Comment: Impossible to say outside of the context of the code it's being used in (and dissecting an entire repository is likely off-topic for this site). E.g. "there clearly aren't any second order derivatives being computed" -- we don't know, because we don't see the function being used anywhere. It also seems like they are _overwriting_ the regular second derivative (0, as you say) by something else -- why they would do this is once again impossible to say from this code alone. It might be best to ask the authors directly.

Comment: As for the second derivative comment, it is clear they are not doing that, to me. Maybe they are overwriting it, but if so, they are overwriting with the value of the first derivative, which seems strange to me. 

I wasn't expecting that answering this question required looking at all the repository, as I figured they used a "standard trick" to make something faster. But it might be as you say, and it is some obscure implementation of the code. I will try contacting the authors, though.